# how can I load path with variable in RequireJS

Tags: requirejs

as title

I try this but I got the error message "Cannot find module"

```js
var path = '../fake-api/data.json';
require(path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like

```
define(["require","../fake-api/data.json"],function(require){
     var data= require("../fake-api/data.json");
});
```